# Named pipe: How to block until closed write side is reopened?

Tags: c++, c, named-pipes, blocking, fifo

I've got a process running which basically serves as a cache and communicates with other processes via named pipes. Periodically these other processes may send messages to the caching process. Now in principle what would work for me in the cache process is something like:

```
while(true) {
    int read_status = read(fifo_fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
    if (read_status > 0) {
        //at least a byte was read -> do something with the message
    }
}
```

But this obviously sucks in terms of performance since `read()` will return immediately on `EOF` resulting in a busy wait loop as soon as there is nothing to read in the pipe. (EDIT) I'm receiving EOF since a writing process may perform the following cycle multiple times: `open()` `write()` `close()`

I'd like to have the whole loop to be blocking if there is no character other than EOF in the pipe. I also investigated on `select()` and `poll()` which both are also not blocking for `EOF`.

---

Why am I needing this?

The caching process is supposed to be a daemon and the other processes are supposed to communicate with this daemon whenever the user invokes respective binaries.

Comment: Eh? Named pipes open at both ends *aren't* at EOF.

Comment: It is like this: A process may open the pipe, write to it, close it and repeat this cycle at any point in time. Does it make sense now with EOF? (I'm not that familiar with this area)

Comment: Ahh! That makes a bit more sense, yes. One option is to open RW -- then it's never EOF -- and another is to use a platform-specific API such as inotify to be notified when someone else opens the pipe.

Comment: ...actually, I think I like the answer from @Brian more; doesn't depend as much on platform-specific tools or underdocumented behavior. Not sure why it's been deleted/withdrawn.

Comment: Somehow his answer disappeared...

Comment: Anyways I'll try the RW option. Where can I get to know stuff like this from?

Comment: @Ben He deleted it. No idea why.

Comment: Instead of RW, I'd actually consider following Brian's suggestion -- close and re-open when you get EOF. Simple, clean, sensible.

Comment: Why would you ever do this in the first place?

Comment: why need to close the pipe? just keep it open.

Comment: @StasJaro, think of `runit`'s control socket as a case where exactly this usage model makes sense.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr, that doesn't help much when the pipe is being used to accept commands from short-lived processes.

Comment: ...Why would you use multiple processes? Just use a new thread

Comment: @CharlesDuffy if allowed, i would recommand OP to try to use socket, then epoll. if the program is of that nature.

Comment: I added a short reasoning section to my question. Btw the RW option does solve it. I will try the formerly available method proposed by brian too though.

Comment: If that fixes it, then I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open your pipe read/write rather than read-only. This will prevent an EOF when the external writer closes it.

Alternately, when receiving an EOF, close the pipe and re-open it.

Comment: I'm just wondering: Suppose I choose the second solution - isn't then there a small time frame between close() and open() during which incoming messages would be discarded?

Comment: Not between `close()` and `open()` no, since any new writers will block.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much - I learned quite something in this question-thread!